# Any scientific basis behind "crystal energy"?

Tags: energy, material-science, crystals, vibrations, matter

I always hear people talking very loosely about the terms "vibration" and "energy" in relation to crystals.

**Is there any scientific basis in "[crystal energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_healing)" or is it purely metaphysical pseudoscience?**

Photons can travel through a crystal, so it can be a medium for energy to travel through, but that isn't exactly energy storage.

**What type of energy can be contained within a crystal if any?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie I appreciate your concern, for I feel the same way about questions when I'm answering in my field of expertise (Biostars & Stackoverflow). However, I believe the question is relevant to physics. It may not be a hw question but I think the answer could segway into a topic on thermodynamics, string theory, or engineering. Crystals are used in computing and amplification, this is a question that extends from that.  I'm only addressing the metaphysical aspect to provide background for why the question is being asked.  This can be a credible resource for those seeking real answers.

Comment: Let me quote from the very first paragraph in the [site tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour): *Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy.* If you wish to ask about phonon scattering, defect dynamics, or any of thousands of topics in condensed matter physics that would be fine. As it is, your question is an unhappy combination of meaningless and too broad.

Comment: Might [skeptics.se] be better suited for debunking myths & products?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because if we rebuff questions like it will help the woo mongers.

Comment: According to [the Physics FAQ](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site): _"a question that proposes a new concept or paradigm, but asks for evaluation of that concept within the framework of current (mainstream) physics is OK."_  By that criterion, this question should be OK.

Comment: I would agree with the above two if this were a query about physics, but since it's mostly about debunking a claim about some New Age mysticism, I'm voting to keep closed. I repeat that [skeptics.se] would be a better place for this question (as it would be for most "debunk this claim" questions).

Comment: My biggest concern about posting this type of question to Skeptics, is that I won't get unbiased answers.  "What type of energy can be contained within a crystal if any?" Is that not a legitimate mainstream physics question when the answers link to actual processes? I only provided the background for insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystals have internal energy including some energy associated with molecular vibrations.

Amorphous materials  have internal energy including some energy associated with molecular vibrations.

In addition to molecular vibrations, crystals can exhibit mechanical (macroscopic) vibrations. An example of a resonant macroscopic vibrator is a tuning fork.  But, note that most tuning forks are made of amorphous metals: crystals offer no special benefit here either.

A few crystals exhibit the piezoelectric effect: a mechanical stress induces an electric field and vice versa.  This is not special to crystals.  Polymers such as polyvinylidene fluoride also exhibit this same effect.

*In sum, there is no special energy that crystals have that other materials do not have.*

### Scams

Googling your the keywords in your question, I found [this site](http://www.healing-crystals-for-you.com/crystal-energy.html) which claims:

> Crystal energy is the power that crystals naturally give off and that
>   you are able to use to heal yourself.

That claim is nonsense.

A [second site](http://www.paganspath.com/meta/stones.htm) says that the "energy" of agate, a merely cryptocrystalline form of silica, has the following properties:

> Compels the truth. Promotes good manners, happiness, intelligence,
>   prosperity, longevity, fertility and good health.

That is also nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is zero physics in "Crystal Energy", which if I understand what you mean, is related to [Crystal Healing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_healing).   There is a good bit of validity to the placebo effect and belief, so a person believing in something, whether the practitioner or the patient, can have an effect or the impression of an effect, but that's not physics either.  I've known a few people who believed in this type of crystal energy and I never heard a word of science come from any of their mouths.

There are, however, real types of crystal energy, such as, you might have heard the term [Quartz Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_clock) or Quartz time piece.    This is because Quarts is a [Piezoelectricitric material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity) that has certain electric properties that respond to pressure and also, can keep very reliable time.

I've heard it theorized that quartz in the ground under tectonic stress can cause charges like lightning to come from the ground and what is sometimes called ball lightning - which is rarely seen and perhaps only recently, confirmed by science.   [Article on same](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/01/140106-earthquake-lights-earthquake-prediction-geology-science/), though, this is all pretty far removed from your question and I've never known anyone who squeezed a quartz crystal hard enough to get an electric charge out of it.

Answer (score 1):

See, a crystal due to its temperature and through various media can be made to vibrate. Now because of the fact that the atoms(lattice points, could be molecules too) are connected with each other, the vibration actually spreads in all directions. Thus this vibration acts as an wave. But the whole of crystal, because of its structure can vibrate only in specific frequencies. So we thus have quantised waves within crystals, which can be treated as particles(due to wave-particle duality) called phonons and these waves carry energy.

Other thing is that when the atoms or molecules that made this crystal were very far apart they did not interacted. So once you put them close the coulomb interactions try to oppose the formation of crystal. So you need to do work to create a crystal. This workdone is stored within a crystal as potential energy.